# Vuejs v-on click doesn't work inside component

Tags: vue.js

I use VueJs and I create the following component with it.

```
var ComponentTest = {
    props: ['list', 'symbole'],
    data: function(){
        return {
            regexSymbole: new RegExp(this.symbole),
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="item in list" 
                    v-html="replaceSymbole(item.name)">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        replaceSymbole: function(name){
            return name.replace(this.regexSymbole, '<span v-on:click="test">---</span>');
        },

        test: function(event){
            console.log('Test ...');
            console.log(this.$el);
        },   
    }
};


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'component-test': ComponentTest,
    },
    data: {
        list: [{"id":1,"name":"@ name1"},{"id":2,"name":"@ name2"},{"id":3,"name":"@ name3"}], 
        symbole: '@'
    },
});
```

and this my html code

```
<div id="app">
    <component-test :list="list" :symbole="symbole"></component-test>
</div>
```

When I click on the "span" tag inside "li" tag, nothing append.

I don't have any warnings and any errors.

How I can call my component method "test" when I click in the "span" tag.

How implement click event for this case.

Comment: If you inspect the generated html, I expect that you see a literal v-on:click attribute on your span element, right?

Comment: yes I see v-on:click in all span tag

Comment: Vue does not interpret your dynamically created span tags. You could either use pure javascript or you programmatically render a Vue component into the span tag, which fires a click event.

Comment: "you cannot use v-html to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition." ([source](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)). You also can check [this answer](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1468#issuecomment-150965507)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use vue directives in strings that you feed to `v-html`. They are not interpreted, and instead end up as actual attributes. You have several options:

- Prepare your data better, so you can use normal templates. You would, for example, prepare your data as an object: `{ linkText: '---', position: 'before', name: 'name1' }`, then render it based on position. I think this is by far the nicest solution.

  ```
  <template>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in preparedList" :key="index">
          <template v-if="item.position === 'before'">
            <span v-on:click="test">{{ item.linkText }}</span>
            {{ item.name }}
          </template>
          <template v-else-if="item.position === 'after'">
            {{ item.name }}
            <span v-on:click="test">{{ item.linkText }}</span>
          </template>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
    props: ["list", "symbole"],

    computed: {
      preparedList() {
        return this.list.map(item => this.replaceSymbole(item.name));
      }
    },

    methods: {
      replaceSymbole: function(question) {
        if (question.indexOf("@") === 0) {
          return {
            linkText: "---",
            position: "before",
            name: question.replace("@", "").trim()
          };
        } else {
          return {
            linkText: "---",
            position: "after",
            name: question.replace("@", "").trim()
          };
        }
      },

      test: function(event) {
        console.log("Test ...");
        console.log(this.$el);
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
  ```
- You can put the click handler on the surrounding li, and filter the event. The first argument to your click handler is the `MouseEvent` that was fired.

  ```
  <template>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item in list" :key="item.id" v-on:click="clickHandler"
            v-html="replaceSymbole(item.name)">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  export default {
    props: ["list", "symbole"],

    data() {
      return {
        regexSymbole: new RegExp(this.symbole)
      };
    },

    computed: {
      preparedList() {
        return this.list.map(item => this.replaceSymbole(item.name));
      }
    },

    methods: {
      replaceSymbole: function(name) {
        return name.replace(
          this.regexSymbole,
          '<span class="clickable-area">---</span>'
        );
      },

      test: function(event) {
        console.log("Test ...");
        console.log(this.$el);
      },

      clickHandler(event) {
        const classes = event.srcElement.className.split(" ");

        // Not something you do not want to trigger the event on
        if (classes.indexOf("clickable-area") === -1) {
          return;
        }

        // Here we can call test
        this.test(event);
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
  ```
- Your last option is to manually add event handlers to your spans. I do **not!!!** recommend this. You **must** also remove these event handlers when you destroy the component or when the list changes, or you will create a memory leak.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: thx for your answer, I can't prepare data better because my name string can contains many symboles , and yes I can't use v-html for this case so I will do in pure js.

Comment: @wpuser000 I don't understand that. The second option uses `v-html` and has the behaviour you expect...

Comment: I try this before <li v-for="item in list">{{ replaceSymbole(item.name) }}</li> but it render in html "<span>---</span>name" so I read the doc and I found this v-html, but I don't read well the doc because I can't use this directive for what I have tried to achieve, i just want replace all symbole with span with click listener. ex: {name:"@ big name @ with many symboles @ "} => <span onclick="test"></span> big name <span onclick="test"></span> with many symbole <span onclick="test"></span>"